# Best way for 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: relational-database

I'm making a social network kind of website where users can make multiple descriptions on stuff on the website. I created a ResourceVersions table which holds all actual content of the database, I then point it to another object in the database where the relationship and type of content is stored. This way I can query the ResourceVersion table to see the most recently changed/added items. For example:

A "Topic" has a "User" which points to a "ResourceVersion" for the description of the user.

OR:

A "Topic" has a "Trick" which points to a "Resource" which has a "ResourceVersion" with a description of the trick.

OR:

A "Trick" has a "UserTrick" which has a "UserVideoClip" which points to a "ResourceVersion" for the description of that clip.

The question now is, what is the best way to setup the 1:1 relationship between the Resources/ResourceVersions and other tables in the database? I now point with the relationship table towards the Resources/ResourceVersions, but should it maybe be the other way around? Or does this not matter?

The point of entry is usually the ResourceVersion (while loading multiple items at least, on the wall for example). So when I query the ResourceTable and join the table which it points to, it has to do a search on the foreign key. If I turn it around it does the search with the primairy key.

Is it true that this will change the speed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was yes, it works better to search for primary keys.